# Could humans evolve into vampires?

Tags: evolution, mythical-creatures, vampires

In my world, vampires evolved from humans. They are carnivorous, need blood to survive, have typical, cliche vampire fangs, they have the night-vision of a cat, and they're sensitive to sunlight.

Normal humans still exist, by the way.

What would cause them to evolve like this?

Comment: Please add the criteria you will use for deciding "best answer" to your post. thx

Comment: Needing blood specifically is the hardest part. If you argue addiction, maybe. However, why would they? Why do you want evolution in your world? If you can't answer it yourself because you lack knowledge about biology, I'm not sure it will add meaningful detail to your world. If I'm mistaken, please include more details in your post. I'm sure any world builder will be able at least some of your criteria partially

Comment: [Sympatric speciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympatric_speciation) is exceedingly tricky given how promiscuous humans are.

Comment: Peter Watts in "Blindsight" has vampires as a subspecies of humans. And there's a ton of scientific bibliography included.

Comment: We need to convert this from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609). As it is, you have no way of selecting a best answer. Whether you do or don't, it's one of the expectations for writing a good question. I'll be happy to retract my close vote once you've explained the criteria for a best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how helpful this answer will be, but I'll give it my best shot. In order for these people to have become vampires, they will need to have been isolated long enough for these unusual traits to effectively create a subspecies of humans.

Nightvision and sensitivity to sunlight could result from people living underground for many generations, and there *are* genetic disorders or mutations that could result in longer, pointer canines. As for being carnivorous and having a dependence on blood, Neanderthals were purely carnivorous, so your best chance is probably having Neanderthals move underground due to some catastrophic event and evolve from there.

Blood dependence when they can eat meat? Sorry, but that's not possible. Your best shot there is for them to have a cultural/psychological obsession with drinking blood. It could be they believe drinking something's blood adds some of that creature's lifeforce to their own, therefore making them more powerful. It could even be that through some placebo magic, it *does.*

Comment: I would disagree with the Location. Vision is not an Important trait in a Cave with Zero light. Nightvision wont do anything there. There is no light. And Nightvision only works with at least a bit of light. 
A Cave system would promote Echolocation and MAYBE heat sensitive eyes if there prey is giving of heat. But you see nothing like this with Animals in caves. All of them (as far as i know) ditch there eyes.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the best way to force Evolution is by limiting Energy. Or in other words Food.

For example, it is known that there are some Animals which have "Equivalents" that live in Caves and have evolved in a very different way. Usually trading there Vision for better Hearing abilitys and smell. As vision is worth fuck all in a Cave system.

The Movie "The Descent" showed this Concept with there "Crawlers"

[image]

Which are basically Humans that adapted to the life in a giant Cave System.

**The Adaptation**

So we need better Vision, a need for something in the Blood and a Sensitivity to sunlight.

The need for very good Vision implies that where ever the guys Evolved, there aint a bunch of light. But it is also not an Enclosed space, because in this case the Eyes would just get worse and Echolocation might replace it over time.

Good Eye sight says to me that your Vampires where not limited by Space for there Evolution. They just had a lack of Light but it wasnt gone all together.

This of course suggests that your Vampires evolved somewhere near the North or South pole, as good Eyesight is much more Helpfull there than Echolocation.

Ok, so bascially North Canada or North Russia. No of course,  good Eyesight can also appear in other locations, but then again, Animals with good Eyes tend to come from colder Places. Like Cats for example which to my knowlege originated way further north.

So next, the Blood. Blood on its own is very useless for Humans. And Drinking it does more Harm than good. So there would need to be something VERY special about Blood to come into question for a food source.

The Movie "Splinter" showed us an Alien Fungy which eat Iron and Thus Blood.

[image]

Now i am not to sure *how* you would use Iron as a Food source but it is probably possible. Furthermore, if the Creatures somehow evolved the need for Iron from external sources, Blood would be the perfect choice.

One thing you could do is to say that the Vampires dont only drink Blood. They can still eat a Big Mac but the need the Iron from the Blood to keep going.

The Sensitivity to Sunlight is easier to answer. Bad Evolution. Evolution is not smarth in any way. And sometimes very dumb traits will make it. Like or Eyes for example. They are trash pretty much.

So how do you make bad Evolution ?

[image]

A small group of Individuals tends to well, not have that much choice in chosing there Partner. And after a while, lets just say everyone is a Motherfucker.

And easy explanation would be to say that all the Inbreading lead to a rear Skincondition to become the norm.

**The Final Timeline**

A long time ago, a large group of Humans was seperated by the rest of the World by some event. For example Rising Sealevel or a Landbrige disapearing.

The Isolated Group evolved way better Eyes over the Years in order to better Hunt the very limited food Supply. This also includes a limitited Capability of detecting Infrared Radiation.

Duo to Inbreading, a rear Skincondition made its way to every new Born Individual. This Condition makes the Skin very sensitive to UV Rays and bascially makes the Skin Burn away. This condition didnt go away because everyone had it. You cant bread something out if everyone has it. No matter how many die.

The need for Blood came about after there Food Supply, for any reason, was reduced. Thus a need for Iron started to develope which was meet by using the to this point unused blood of there prey.

Sorry for the Bad English, i am German.

Comment: Your English ain't "bad" :)

Answer (score 0):

## Selection Pressure

In order for a species to evolve a certain trait there has to be a reproductive fitness advantage to those traits. So for the traits you've listed, here are some examples of appropriate circumstances.

1. Low light vision (and high sensitivity): The earth (or at least the region where these creatures evolve) is in near darkness with the sun blotted out for many hundreds of years. Perhaps the result of a super-volcano, nuclear fallout, or asteroid impact. But it has to be so drastic that it actually kills those who can't see well, allowing those who can see better to be able to survive to reproduce, while others don't. It also helps if this is getting progressively worse so that you only need to be a little more sensitive at first to get an advantage, but as time goes on it becomes more and more necessary in order to survive.
2. Carnivorous: The subsistence economy for this group is not sustainable with farms or other agriculture, as such they need to subsist on hunted meat in order to survive (those who can't need to not be able to reproduce, and probably die). The hunted food source would probably need to be either migratory or subsist on plants that the "Human/Vampires" can't eat like grasses. Otherwise the human/vampires could just eat the same plant foods that those animals do and would continue to be omnivores.
3. Fangs: This might be the hardest one to come up with a reason for as humans are already reasonably suited to consuming meat without sharper teeth, and it's unlikely that we would actually use our mouths as weapons (as most historical carnivores do) when we have the ability to use tools with our wonderful hands with opposable thumbs. The best reasoning here is that it becomes incredibly popular to have sharp teeth, so much so that everyone wants to have children with a sharp toothed individual, and the ones who don't have sharp teeth can't persuade anyone to mate with them (even if the others don't have sharp teeth either). The only other way this could go is if there is a particular abundant food source that can only be used by those with teeth and no tool can really help them to eat it (or such tools are rare).

Evolution is a bit of a fickle mistress, and you need very particular set of selection pressures in order to get a desired result. Of course, evolution doesn't usually set out with an end point in mind when selection pressures come up, which is going to be your challenge in your story.

Comment: that remind me of japan woman with their [yaeba teeth trend](https://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/scaled/2013/02/01/article-2271585-17477AAA000005DC-730_308x185.jpg)